# 7zip file compression mode store using command prompt is not working?

Tags: compression, nant, store, mode, 7zip

I need to compress my data folder using 7zip (compression mode store) from my nant script. If I compressed from command prompt its not working properly. It taking some other compression mode.

This is my code

7zip.exe `a mydatafolder.7z -ptest -mx0 mytarget`

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of 7zip.exe?
Which compression mode is used in the existing 7z file?
Can you attach\link to a sample 7z archive that you have tried and behaves unexpectedly when trying to add another file without compression?
I am not sure if you can use mixed compression mode in a 7z archive or not.